# How to apply turnstile effect for each UI element in a page

Tags: windows-phone-7, animation, navigation

When the application starts, I have a splashscreen after which the mainpage.xaml is loaded. The Mainpage has a lot of UI elements such as buttons and textblocks. It takes about a second or two to load this so I thought some animation could fill in the gap. Else it might look a bit awkward.

Windows phone native application such as the messages, uses some default animation when the page opens right, the pivot headers swivels in then followed by the other UI, the door opening kind of thing. After a bit of researchin I found that they are the default fault turnstile animations.

```
    <toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardIn"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardIn"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
    </toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardOut"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardOut"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
    </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
```

So I have put in the above code just above the `</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>` tag of the MainPage. But the elements of the page do not have the turnstile animation, how can i apply it to the other UI elements in the page?? Could someone  guide me on this?

Alfah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/) also has the `TurnstileFeather` transition. This basically seems to be activated as follows,

- Change App.xaml.cs so that `RootFrame = new TransitionFrame()`
- Include the toolkit in the XAML for the animated page e.g. `xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"`
- Include the following XAML just after the opening tag (similar to what you pasted),

> ```
> <toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
>   <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
>       <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
>           <toolkit:TurnstileFeatherTransition Mode="BackwardIn"/>
>       </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
>       <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
>           <toolkit:TurnstileFeatherTransition Mode="ForwardIn"/>
>       </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
>   </toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
> </toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
> <toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
>   <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
>       <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
>           <toolkit:TurnstileFeatherTransition Mode="BackwardOut"/>
>       </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
>       <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
>           <toolkit:TurnstileFeatherTransition Mode="ForwardOut"/>
>       </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
>   </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
> </toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
> ```

- Finally on each container element place the following attribute `toolkit:TurnstileFeatherEffect.FeatheringIndex="0"` with the number relating to the order in which you want the elements to peel away in. e.g.

> ```
> <TextBlock toolkit:TurnstileFeatherEffect.FeatheringIndex="0">Cheetah</TextBlock>
> <TextBlock toolkit:TurnstileFeatherEffect.FeatheringIndex="1">Hare</TextBlock>
> <TextBlock toolkit:TurnstileFeatherEffect.FeatheringIndex="2">Tortoise</TextBlock>
> ```

Answer (score 5):

What you are referring to is called a "feather turnstile" or "peel" transition.

There are three implementations that I know of:

- [Colin Eberhardt's "peel" animation as part of his Metro In Motion series](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/03/metro-in-motion-part-2-peel-animations/) (free, includes source)
- [Clarity Consulting's turnstile transition](http://blogs.claritycon.com/blog/2010/10/13/wp7-page-transitions-sample/) (free, includes source)
- [Telerik's RadControls for Windows Phone](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone.aspx) (not free, no source)

None of the above integration into the toolkit's transition framework. I've considered doing so myself, but never had the time.

Comment: Thank you, yes i was referring to feather turnstile. But now it looks like feather turnstile can be used only with listboxes :(

Comment: @alfah the 'peel' animation from Colin Eberhardt does not require the items to be a listbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can use feather transition on any control like i have used textblock in this example.

```
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
<toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
<toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
<toolkit:TurnstileFeatherTransition Mode="BackwardIn"/>
</toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
<toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
<toolkit:TurnstileFeatherTransition Mode="ForwardIn"/>
</toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
</toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
<toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
<toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
<toolkit:TurnstileFeatherTransition Mode="BackwardOut"/>
</toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
<toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
<toolkit:TurnstileFeatherTransition Mode="ForwardOut"/>
</toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
</toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>

if you are using pivot then use this

<controls:Pivot toolkit:TurnstileFeatherEffect.FeatheringIndex="0" Title="MY APPLICATION">
```

and then use the effect in any control

```
<TextBlock toolkit:TurnstileFeatherEffect.FeatheringIndex="1" Text="Hello" FontSize="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.